# URI::InvalidURIError (Ruby ver: 1.9.3, Rails: 3.2.15)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try generating a Rails app via `rails new new_project`, I am getting this error:

```
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  ........
  ........
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep


  run  bundle install
  /home/manish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:213:\
  in ` 'initialize': the scheme http does not accept registry \
  part:manish:password@my_company.com:port_no; (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

To add more to this error it comes when I run `gem install ruby-debug` also.

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.15'    
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'    
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Could someone explain me what this error is and how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Which ruby and rails version you have?

Comment: @SSR I have added in title

Comment: @SSR when project is new 'routes.rb' doesn't play any role if I am not wrong

Comment: Please post your Gemfile

Comment: See when you create a project and then it just start bundling. so that bundle will take information from gem file of your project which will come up with all files. and then it just create a gemlock file according you gem file.

Comment: Oh sorry that was my mistake

Comment: I was asking to you for gem file, but i wrote it route.

Comment: Are you behind any sort of proxy? What does `echo $http_proxy` in shell gives back?

Comment: ruby's URI.parse doesn't allow underscore in URLs.  Change "my_company" to something else or use a different URI implementation as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197605/alternative-to-uri-parse-that-allows-hostnames-to-contain-an-underscore)

Comment: check this http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/114986-the-scheme-http-does-not-accept-registry-part, may be this could help you.

Comment: @rb512 It is not under_score, just replaced the domain name with that.

Comment: @kiddorails I am behind proxy and it gives the proxy details. Do u need any details for that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to https in source => 'https://rubygems.org' in Gemfile. Have you tried with :-

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I guess this is related to some mapping issue of proxy or something. Still struggling to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem which turned out to be the problem in [Ruby itself](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/issues/391):

> The problem is related to the uri component of Ruby itself, which
>   tries to match the userinfo part of the URI

I had a non-standard character in password (#) which couldn't be correctly handled by URI regexp. So I fixed ***/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb***:

```
   -USERINFO = "(?:[#{UNRESERVED};:&=+$,]|#{ESCAPED})*"
   +USERINFO = "(?:[#{UNRESERVED};:&=+$,\#]|#{ESCAPED})*"
```

and it worked. Note, that to support DOMAIN backslash it should be:

```
  USERINFO = "(?:[#{UNRESERVED};:&=+$,\#\\\\]|#{ESCAPED})*"
```

according to [this](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/issues/391). You can find this **uri/common.rb** file in all installations of ruby that you use with **find** (e.g. if you use rvm it will be something like ***.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb***)